# Dynamic field for Model in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

(Using Django 2.0, Python 3.6, and Django Rest Framework 3.8)

I'm trying to create an appointment scheduling API where `Client` can schedule a session with `UserB` based on `UserB`'s availability. `UserB` has a field which displays their availability in the `UserB` model (in addition to other fields).

`UserB` model is as follows:

```
class Users(models.Model):

    profile = models.OneToOneField(TriUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    trainer_certifications = models.TextField(max_length=5000, default='')

    trainer_bio = models.TextField(max_length=5000, default='')

    trainer_profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="gyminfofiles/trainers/images/", null=True, blank=True)

    gym = models.ForeignKey(Gym, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default = '', null=True, blank=True, related_name='GymClassRelatedName')

    workout_types = models.ManyToManyField(WorkoutTypes,)

    availability = models.ManyToManyField('Availability', related_name='AvailabilityRelatedName', blank=True)

    trainer_bookings = models.ManyToManyField('BookAppointment', related_name='BookAppointmentRelatedName', blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.profile)
```

Where, the `Availability` model can be seen below:

```
class Availability(models.Model):

    SUNDAY = 'SUNDAY'
    MONDAY = 'MONDAY'
    TUESDAY = 'TUESDAY'
    WEDNESDAY = 'WEDNESDAY'
    THURSDAY = 'THURSDAY'
    FRIDAY = 'FRIDAY'
    SATURDAY = 'SATURDAY'

    AVAILABILITY_DATE_CHOICES = (
        (SUNDAY, 'Sunday'),
        (MONDAY, 'Monday'),
        (TUESDAY, 'Tuesday'),
        (WEDNESDAY, 'Wednesday'),
        (THURSDAY, 'Thursday'),
        (FRIDAY, 'Friday'),
        (SATURDAY, 'Saturday'),
    )
    availability_date = models.CharField(
        max_length = 9,
        choices=AVAILABILITY_DATE_CHOICES
    )

    T1200_1230_AM = '12:00 am - 12:30 am'
    T1230_100_AM = '12:30 am - 1:00 am'
    T100_130_AM = '1:00 am - 1:30 am'
    T130_200_AM = '1:30 am - 2:00 am'
    T200_230_AM = '2:00 am - 2:30 am'
    T230_300_AM = '2:30 am - 3:00 am'

    AVAILABILITY_TIME_CHOICES = (
        (T1200_1230_AM, '12:00 am - 12:30 am'),
        (T1230_100_AM, '12:30 am - 1:00 am'),
        (T100_130_AM, '1:00 am - 1:30 am'),
        (T130_200_AM, '1:30 am - 2:00 am'),
        (T200_230_AM, '2:00 am - 2:30 am'),
        (T230_300_AM, '2:30 am - 3:00 am'),
    )
    availability_time = models.CharField(
        max_length=18,
        choices=AVAILABILITY_TIME_CHOICES
    )


    def __str__(self):
        return str((self.availability_date, self.availability_time))
```

When the `Client` tries to schedule an appointment, they are directed to a model with the following structure:

`class BookAppointment(models.Model):
    User_to_schedule_with = models.OneToOneField(Users)
    AvailableUserTimes_to_choose_from = (THIS IS WHER I'M STUCK)`

where the `User_to_schedule_with` field will be a dropdown which displays various Users the Client can schedule an appointment with (ex: UserB, UserC, UserD, etc.). After the Client has selected a User, I want the field `AvailableUserTimes_to_choose_from` to populate with the availability specific to the selected User. How would I be able to accomplish this, and how would I be able to access the one specific field `availability` from the `UserB` model?

`UserB` model is as follows:

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: may you please include your `UserB` model in the question as well?

Comment: @Qubad sure thing, just included it in a new edit

Comment: may you also include `Availability` model for clearer picture here?

Comment: @mrehan absolutely, just added it